# Skyfield timescale object does not include leapseconds during creation of a UTC date?

Tags: python, datetime, skyfield

Say I have a unix epoch time stamp `1664203669`. When generating a UTC date from this time stamp using `datetime` I get the following date.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1664203669).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Out[25]: '2022-09-26 14:47:49'
```

Though when using `skyfield` I get the following date

```
from skyfield.api import load
load.timescale().utc(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1664203669).utc_strftime()
Out[27]: '2022-09-26 14:47:22 UTC'
```

These UTC times are 27 seconds apart. Corresponding with the total number of leap seconds since 1970 to the given time stamp. From the [`skyfield` documentation](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-time.html) this construction should handle leap seconds, but it doesn't seem to?

**Why are these two date different?**

Comment: that constructor seems to just add the seconds to the preceding attributes; however Unix time excludes leap seconds, so if you add that amount of seconds to the epoch, resulting date/time is missing leap seconds.

Comment: @FObersteiner I guess my issue is that `skyfield.timelib.Timescale.utc` ( https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/blob/dd2fd90b661d93dfe292357bcca86cf0dedb169a/skyfield/timelib.py#L189 ) seemingly attempts to calculate the number of leap seconds. But it's wrong? I mean I know I am the actually wrong one somehow, but I don't see how that linked code is not accounting for leap seconds..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked the two libraries two different questions, and they each answered correctly.

You asked Python's `datetime` module: *What does the Unix timestamp 1664203669 correspond to?*

To make the math easy, Unix timestamps treat each day as containing exactly 60×60×24 seconds. This means that Unix timestamps can't refer to leap seconds; they skip them as if they don't exist. So `datetime` can simply divide 1664203669 by the number of seconds in a normal day, and then compute hours and minutes from the remainder.

You asked Skyfield something different: *What UTC date and time followed exactly 1,664,203,669 seconds after the beginning of 1970?*

Because Skyfield knows all about leap seconds, it understands that 27 of those 1.66-million seconds get eaten up by leap seconds through the years between 1970 and 2022, so it returns a time of day that's earlier.